# Matlab How to Use uicalendar

Tags: matlab, user-interface

I am trying to use uicalendar to create a GUI Calendar that will allow the user to select a date instead of having to enter one manually. I've tried finding help online on how to use uicalendar but all that I found is a page on Matlab's website

http://www.mathworks.com/help/finance/uicalendar-graphical-user-interface.html#f11-107599

Whenever I try using uicalendar, I get the following message error message from Matlab:

```
Error using uicalendar>validateparams (line
1549)
Undefined function 'parsepvpairs' for input
arguments of type 'cell'.

Error in uicalendar (line 136)
[paramValStruct, ~] = validateparams(nargin,
varargin, paramNames);
```

I am not sure what this error message means or what I am doing wrong. I have tried just entering "uicalendar" I've tried entering uicalendar with some inputs to specify some properties of the uicalendar but I always get the same error.

Edit: I have also tried performing the following example that was given on Matlab's website:

```
function uicalendarGUIExample

f = figure('Name','uicalendarGUIExample');
dateTextHandle = uicontrol(f,'Style','Text',...
    'String','Date',...
    'Horizontalalignment','left',...
    'Position',[100 200 50 20]);
dateEditBoxHandle = uicontrol(f,'Style','Edit',...
    'Position',[140 200 100 20],...
    'BackgroundColor','w');
calendarButtonHandle = uicontrol(f,'Style','PushButton',...
    'String','Select a single date',...
    'Position',[275 200 200 20],...
    'callback',@pushbutton_cb);

    function pushbutton_cb(hcbo,eventStruct)
        uicalendar('Weekend',[1 0 0 0 0 0 1],...
            'SelectionType',1,...
            'DestinationUI',dateEditBoxHandle);
    end
end
```

When I run uicalendarGUIExample and click on the pushbutton it gives the following error:

```
Undefined function 'uicalendar' for input arguments of type 'char'.

Error in uicalendarGUIExample/pushbutton_cb (line 19)
        uicalendar('Weekend',[1 0 0 0 0 0 1],...

Error while evaluating uicontrol Callback
```

Can anyone try and copy and paste the code and see if they run into a similar issue?

Thanks.

Comment: sounds trivial but do you have the Financial Toolbox? If not then I'm afraid you don't have access to uicalendar

Comment: What calls are you making specifically? Have you looked at the syntax in [the documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/finance/uicalendar.html) to make sure your calls are correct? The error (admittedly not a very well explained one) suggests that you are not entering your parameters correctly.

Comment: I am not sure if I have Financial Toolbox but my guess is probably not.

Comment: @leinadw2 the output of `ver` should tell you what toolboxes are installed

Comment: I have tried following the exact syntax in the example given on Matlab's website. http://www.mathworks.com/help/finance/uicalendar-graphical-user-interface.html#f11-107599

Comment: @Benoit_11 I entered "ver" and Financial Toolbox Version 5.0 was on the list so I guess that I must have it.

Comment: ok then. Can you show how you call uicalendar? It seems to not accept cells as arguments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that someone made a date picker function that does exactly what I need. They have it posted on the Matlab file exchange.

http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/31387-datepicker

Thanks for everyone's help.